# EJB Timer (@Schedule) not recognized by WildFly when inside a JAR which is also inside an EAR

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ear

I have an EAR file with 3 WARs and some common dependencies within lib/ folder. One of those dependencies has an EJB with a scheduled method, but it seems that the server is not recognizing it. No evidence in log, no code executed.

But when I deploy a simple war with the same jar within WEB-INF/lib, it works. I've already tried to package the jar as an ejb-jar with the maven plugin, but no success at all.

Any ideas on what must be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jars in the `lib` directory of an EAR are not considered to be EJB jars and their content is not considered at deployment time in that respect. The `lib` directory only exists to make it easier to provide library jars whose classes are automatically made visible to all the modules in an EAR file.

Your EAR file contains a META-INF/application.xml file that lists out the various `modules` that it contains. Prior to Java EE 6, only ejb-modules were considered for potential EJBs. Java EE 6 and newer added web-modules to that list. All jars within a web-module's WEB-INF/lib directory are considered to be part of the web-module, even if they contain ejb-jars. Any ejb-jar.xml files found within a web-module are merged together. This applies even if the web-module is deployed as a standalone WAR file.

Comment: You're right. Putting the jar as an ejb module within the EAR solved the issue. Thanks.